# Which Listener to use to notify a change in a Containment?

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp, emf

I'm using Zest to visualize the emf model elements. I right click a node and a menu pops up, select a menu item and at last a wizard pops up. In performedFinish I create the elements in a containment. How can I grab and/or get notified when a new element is being added in a containment and send it back to the caller? (add/remove that listener)

KR

Moonstar

Comment: Is it a Zest specific question, or you just need to be notified of containment changes in your code?

Comment: Get notified which model element was being added in the containment  after having invoked a wizard which creates a new model element in a containment after the performFinish. Like a back call to the place the wiazrd was being called to link the new created object with an EReference of an other model element.

Answer (score 1):

There is a class EContentAdapter. It tracks containment notifications of all children, not just direct children. So if you add this adapter to the root of your model, you can track containment notifications, extracting information about new elements.

Comment: Thank you very much. Gonna try to find more information on this and try it.